# Data has been passed to the next viewcontroller with didselect in tableview. error when pop to the previous viewcontroller [index out of range]

Tags: swift3

I passed the value to the next view controller with didselect in tableview using navigation controller.pushviewcontroller .it works fine. but i pop back and didselect the next row of tableview it gives index out of range error

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let vc = ChooseItemVC()
  vc.restaurantID = selectedID.branches[indexPath.row].restaurantId
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Please check the viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear method, is there anything you messed up with your array or tableView like deleting the row from your tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bigger portion of your code would help, what I can guess for what I see is that maybe you have something in your viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method that resets the content of "selectedID.branches", if you set the content of that array to empty in either of those methods that could probably be causing the problem.

Sorry for not adding just a comment, but I must have 50 of reputation to do so.